# using HEX() in Mysql to convert character encoding

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a column with latin1 character encoding.
Can anyone explain why this happens?

When I run:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT unhex(convert(hex(text) USING utf8)) FROM translation_target
```

I get correctly displaying characters.

When I run:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT text FROM sanus2013_dev1.translation_target;
```

I get the corrupted characters:

So I thought if I ran something like this:

```
UPDATE translation_target SET text = unhex(convert(hex(text) USING utf8));
```

I would be able to use:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT text FROM sanus2013_dev1.translation_target;
```

and see the correct character encoding. can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Edit: The Column `translation_target` has `CHARACTER SET latin1` with `COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci`

Not sure if this helps but I used an ALTER TABLE COLUMN statement to change the CHARACTER SET to utf8 and the COLLATION to utf8_unicode_ci;

running:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT unhex(convert(hex(text) USING utf8)) FROM translation_target;
```

shows corrupted characters.

When I change the character set and collation back to latin1 it works again.

Comment: Well, I have seen this article some days ago and it seems to be very complete and instructive.
It explains the basics of charset and collation to the most complex concept.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
UPDATE translation_target 
    SET text=convert(cast(convert(text using  latin1) as binary) using utf8) 
    FROM translation_target;
```